# For of loop not being entered

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an issue using .entries on an array to get index and value in a for of loop

```
ranks: any = {
    total: 100,    
    percentages: [
        {
            percentage: 33
        },
        {
            percentage: 33
        },
        {
            percentage: 34
        }
    ]
};

getMax(i: number){
    var max: number = 100;
    for (let [index,value] of this.ranks.percentages.entries()) {
        console.log(index, value.percentage);
        if(index !== i){
            max -= value.percentage;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

The console log is never logged in this case. I made a simple example that works so I must be missing something clearly obvious.

```
array = [
  { name:12 },
  { name:23 },
  { name:34 }
]

for (let [index, value] of array.entries()) {
  console.log(index, value.name);
}
```

I'd normally try to console.log things to get at the issue but I'm not sure what to log or how I could use breakpoints since it skips over it.

Comment: Looks like you call `entries` as a function `this.ranks.percentages.entries()`. Shouldn't those parentheses be left out?

Comment: Did you try putting `for` loop inside `try...catch`. I think it should throw proper exception.

Comment: When I don't use parentheses it throws an exception

Comment: put getMax in a try catch and nothing was caught

Comment: I am not familiar with all of the colons you've got in there. What is `getMax(i: number)` supposed to mean? (vs `getMax(i)`) or `ranks: any =` (vs `ranks =`) can you link to documentation of that syntax?

Comment: It's just typescript with strongly typed variables https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: javascript isn't typescript

Comment: You're right, I'm not doing anything besides some type checking that isn't in JavaScript though

Comment: If you are using typescript or some other language that compiles down to javascript, like coffeescript, you should tag the question that way.

Comment: Although I don't know why, you could try `for (entry of Array.from(this.ranks.percentages.entries()))`. I haven't had time to look into it further, but it seems that it could be a bug in TS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TS compiles the `for` statement as

```
for (var _i = 0, _a = ranks.percentages.entries(); _i < _a.length; _i++) {
```

`length` of an iterator is undefined, so the for loop becomes a no-op.

In other words, it does not seem to know that `entries()` is yielding an iterable. Are you getting a compilation error about `entries`?

If you compile down to ES6, this works.

If you just want to get your code working, then just rewrite it as a basic for loop.

Comment: Just learned all this and took the exact steps you outlined. Started getting the compilation error after not getting it for a while, wtf TS, switched to a basic for loop and everything is working